# How do I display tags for a custom post type single page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, single, terms

I am trying to display tags related to a custom post type entry on the single page.

My Custom post type is registered as 'Blog' and the here is the code for the tags in my functions.php file:

```
function blog_tag_init() 
{

$labels = array(
    'name' => 'Tags',
    'singular_name' => 'Tag',
    'search_items' => 'Search Tags',
    'all_items' => 'All Tags',
    'parent_item' => 'Parent Tag',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Tag:',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Tag',
    'update_item' => 'Update Tag',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add Tag',
    'new_item_name' => 'New Tag Name',
    'menu_name' => 'Tags',
);

register_taxonomy( 'blog-tags', 'blog',
    array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'query_var'         => true
    )
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'blog_tag_init' );
```

In my single template file I use the code below to display the tags:

```
<p><?php the_tags(' and tagged under ', ', '); ?> </p>
```

However the tags do not appear on the single page and I have no idea why because it all looks set up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `the_tags` in the custom post type. You should use [`the_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms) instead.

So, you can use this function to get the tags:

```
the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'blog-tags', ' and tagged under ', ', ');
```

Comment: unfortunately the tags do not appear after I change the code to your suggestion.

Comment: @NeelamKhan Sorry i had a mistype. I forgot to change `post_tag` to `blog-tags`. Also be sure the pass the ID, or use `get_the_ID()`.